# Express js - Error handling in middleware

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I have a route

```
 app.get("/some/url/", function(req, res){ res.sendStatus(404) })
```

I am trying to handle or catch this 404 in express error handling middleware and it is not working

```
 app.use(function(err, req, res, next){do something here})
```

Any help how do i capture the error thrown by route in the middleware.

Comment: The response is still successfully communicated, regardless of the status code, so Express doesn't consider it an error. You can, however, raise an error yourself – `res.sendStatus(404); next(new Error('404 Not found'));`.

Comment: A little more meaningful and less generic title to your question would be good.

Comment: please add your code snippet...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
app.get("/some/url/", function(req, res) {
    // Generate Error yourself.
    throw new Error("Generated Error.");
});

// global error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    console.dir(err);
    
    if(err) {
        // Your Error Status code and message here.
        res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
    }

    // Send Some valid Response
});
```

Comment: Just tried your solution, the global error handler was not able to catch the error. It still crashed

Comment: Better if you can share the code and detailed issue.